# how to get 30 if a is 25 using python

Tags: python, math

this is my code:

```
from math import ceil
a = 25
a = float(a/10)
a = int(ceil(a))*10
print a
```

i get 20, but i want get 30 ,

the next is what i want get:

```
if the a is 22 , i want get 20
if the a is 25 , i want get 30
if the a is 27 , i want get 30
if the a is 21 , i want get 20
```

so  what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: try a = a/10.0 instead of a = float(a/10)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [`round()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round):

```
print int(round(25, -1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [round() method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round)

```
>>> num = 25
>>> round_num = int(round(num, -1))
>>> round_num
30

>>> num = 22
>>> round_num = int(round(num, -1))
>>> round_num
20
```

and so on.